# netty4: MessageToMessageDecoder<DatagramPacket> gives only first 2048 octets

Tags: json, udp, apache-camel, netty

I'm using **Camel 2.15.3** and **camel-netty4**, and since upgrading from camel-netty3, I'm having problems receiving full JSON messages via UDP.  Each JSON message is about 3 to 5 kbytes, but my **MessageToMessageDecoder** implementation is only giving me the first 2048 (i.e. 2k bytes).  From a test program, I send in one UDP message, and from my debug prints within my **MessageToMessageDecoder** it shows that the decode() method is only called once.

I'm currently reading through **Netty In Action**, but i see this in my log file: **UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 2048, cap: 2048))**

I desperately need to get this fixed in production, and just need to be able to receive JSON messasges via UDP and send them through my Camel routes. I'm confused about what is the best framing (if any) to use?

With netty3 this was working fine and I had a **UdpPacketDecoder implements ChannelUpstreamHandler** that invoked **Channels.fireMessageReceived(ctx, message, me.getRemoteAddress())** to fire the message to the next handler and it seemed to work fine.

My route looks like the below. It consumes from netty4:udp and produces to a SEDA queue, just for now while testing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <route startupOrder="104" customId="true" id="ROUTE_ID_RAW_CQMS_EVENTS" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
            <from uri="netty4:udp://devserver-09.dev.s.mission.net:11111?serverPipelineFactory=#CQMS_SERVER_PIPELINE_FACTORY_ROUTE_ID_RAW_CQMS_EVENTS&amp;keepAlive=true&amp;sync=false&amp;receiveBufferSize=26214400&amp;sendBufferSize=26214400&amp;allowDefaultCodec=false&amp;disconnectOnNoReply=false&amp;receiveBufferSizePredictor=8192"/>
            <setProperty propertyName="CamelCharsetName" id="setProperty1">
                    <expressionDefinition>iso-8859-1</expressionDefinition>
            </setProperty>
            <threads poolSize="7" maxPoolSize="14" threadName="threads_ROUTE_ID_RAW_CQMS_EVENTS" callerRunsWhenRejected="true" id="threads1">
                    <to uri="seda:SEDA_INPUT_QUEUE_102?size=200000&amp;concurrentConsumers=10&amp;waitForTaskToComplete=Never&amp;failIfNoConsumers=true&amp;timeout=10000" id="to1"/>
                    <setProperty propertyName="CamelCharsetName" id="setProperty2">
                            <expressionDefinition>iso-8859-1</expressionDefinition>
                    </setProperty>
            </threads>
    </route>
```

I print out the received DatagramPacket, which shows this:  UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 2048, cap: 2048))

Here is my MessageToMessageDecoder implementation:

```
    package com.mission.mplr.multiprotocollistenerrouter;

    import com.vonage.mplr.utils.MiscUtils;
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext; // Represents the "binding" between a ChannelHandler and the ChannelPipeline.
    import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
    import io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;        // The org.slf4j.Logger interface is the main user entry point of SLF4J API.
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; // Utility class producing Loggers for various logging APIs, most notably for log4j.


    public class UdpDatagramDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<DatagramPacket> {
            private static final Logger logger      = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UdpDatagramDecoder.class);
            private static final Logger errorLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ERROR_LOGGER");
            private final String CHARSET_NAME;

            UdpDatagramDecoder(String charsetName) {
                    this.CHARSET_NAME = charsetName;
            }

            @Override

            public boolean acceptInboundMessage(Object msg) throws Exception {
                    return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext chc, DatagramPacket packet, List out) throws Exception {
                    logger.info("decode(): ENTER");

                    logger.info("decode(): Received datagram = {}", packet);

                    String packetAsString = packet.content().toString(Charset.forName(CHARSET_NAME));

                    if(packetAsString == null) {
                            return; // Nothing to do
                    } else {
                            out.add(packetAsString);
                            packet.retain();
                    }

                    logger.info("decode(): bodyBytesAsString[size={}] = {}", packetAsString.length(), packetAsString);

                    String bodyBytesAsHex = MiscUtils.stringAsHex(packetAsString, CHARSET_NAME);
                    logger.info("decode(): bodyBytesAsHex[size={}] = {}", bodyBytesAsHex.length(), bodyBytesAsHex);

                    logger.info("decode(): EXIT");
            }
    }
    // ------------- end --------------
```

My server pipeline has this initChannel() implementation:

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
    logger.trace("initChannel(): ENTER");

    ChannelPipeline channelPipeline = ch.pipeline();
    serverInvoked = true;  

    String theSourceRouteId = consumer.getRoute().getId();
    logger.debug("initChannel(): consumer = {}, theSourceRouteId = {}", consumer.toString(), theSourceRouteId);

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Here we add the custom UDP datagram decoder. Decoders are typically
    // stateful, thus we create a new instance with every pipeline.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    String udpPacketDecoderName = "CQMS_UDP_DATAGRAM_DECODER_" + theSourceRouteId;
    logger.debug("initChannel(): Adding {}", udpPacketDecoderName);
    channelPipeline.addLast(udpPacketDecoderName, new UdpDatagramDecoder(CHARSET_NAME));

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Default Camel ServerChannelHandler for the consumer, to allow Camel to route the message.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    String serverChannelHandlerName = "CQMS_SERVER_CHANNEL_HANDLER_" + theSourceRouteId;
    logger.debug("initChannel(): Adding {}", serverChannelHandlerName);
    channelPipeline.addLast(serverChannelHandlerName, new ServerChannelHandler(consumer));

    logger.trace("initChannel(): EXIT");
}
```

Comment: You're pretty optimistic with these UDP datagram sizes. The generally accepted safe limit for a UDP datagram is either 534 or 576, can never remember which.

Answer (score 1):

Netty uses 2048 as upper limit for datagram packets by default. You can change this via setting your own instance of FixedRecvByteBufAllocator on the Bootstrap. Not sure how this can be done via Camel though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much Norman!  Below is the solution that works for Camel 2.15.3.
Basically, we read the upper limit from the application's configuration and set it within the ServerInitializerFactory's **initChannel(Channel ch)** method.

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {

    ChannelPipeline channelPipeline = ch.pipeline();
    serverInvoked = true;  

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Here we add the custom UDP datagram decoder. Decoders are typically
    // stateful, thus we create a new instance with every pipeline.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    String udpDecoderName = "UDP_DECODER_" + theSourceRouteId;
    channelPipeline.addLast(udpDecoderName, new UdpPacketDecoder_ADAPTER(CHARSET_NAME));

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Netty4 has default of 2048 bytes as upper limit for datagram packets.
    // Here we override the default upper limit based on a config param.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------  
    if(ConfigManager.getInstance().getRecvByteBufAllocator() > 0) {
        ch.config().setRecvByteBufAllocator(new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(ConfigManager.getInstance().getRecvByteBufAllocator()));
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // Add string encoder (downstream) / string decoder (upstream)
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // For decoding from a ChannelBuffer to a String object
    String stringDecoderName = "SERVER_PIPELINE_STRING_DECODER_" + theSourceRouteId;
    channelPipeline.addLast(stringDecoderName, STR_DECODER);

    // For encoding from a String object into a ChannelBuffer
    String stringEncoderName = "SERVER_PIPELINE_STRING_ENCODER_" + theSourceRouteId;
    channelPipeline.addLast(stringEncoderName, STR_ENCODER);

    // For encoding from a String object into a DatagramPacket
    String datagramPacketEncoderName = "SERVER_PIPELINE_DATAGRAM_PACKET_ENCODER_" + theSourceRouteId;
    channelPipeline.addLast(datagramPacketEncoderName, DATAGRAM_PACKET_ENCODER);

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Default Camel ServerChannelHandler for the consumer, to allow Camel to route the message.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    String serverChannelHandlerName = "SERVER_CHANNEL_HANDLER_" + theSourceRouteId;
    channelPipeline.addLast(serverChannelHandlerName, new ServerChannelHandler(consumer));
}
```